# Why does including the same struct from the same file into multiple crates result in a type mismatch error?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I created the following file structure:

```
mod_test/src/
|- main.rs
|- a_module.rs
|- lib.rs
```

**a_module.rs**

```
pub struct A {}
```

**lib.rs**

```
mod a_module;
pub fn run(s: a_module::A) {}
```

**main.rs**

```
extern crate mod_test;

mod a_module;

fn main() {
    let b: a_module::A b = a_module::A {};
    mod_test::run(b);
}
```

The parameter type of the `run` function in the lib file is obviously the same as `b` is (except for the namespace, it's the `A` struct in both cases). Since `run` is imported in another namespace, the compiler tells me that there is a type mismatch:

```
expected: modTest::a_module::A -- got: a_module::A
```

I know how to fix that behavior, but why is this behavior intended?

Why can't the compiler see that the `A` struct is the exact same, since it refers to the exact same file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *not using the same type*, as far as the compiler is concerned. Rust has *nominal typing*, not *structural typing*. You may be familiar from structural typing from languages such as TypeScript.

> except for the namespace

The namespace, including the crate, is part of what makes a type unique. You have imported the same file multiple times in different crates. That's no different from having identical structs in different modules:

```
mod a {
    struct A;
}

mod b {
    struct A;
}
```

These should not be the same type.

The fact that they are the same file doesn't really matter to the compiler. If it did, there'd be really strange issues around symlinks and hardlinks...

All that matters is where you've placed the type in a crate and module hierarchy.

See also:

- [Nominative And Structural Typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?NominativeAndStructuralTyping)